# Run code on certain pages only?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I want my google chrome extension to change the HTML of google.com/trade to `???` and the HTML of yahoo.com/trade to `<<<`, however this code I found after doing some research is not working. I've made sure I have the manifest correct, and I have all the permissions needed, but for some reason it just won't work.

```
$(function() {
if (window.location.href.match(/google\.com\/trade/i)) {
    $("html").html("???");
} else if (window.location.href.match(/yahoo\.com\/trade/i)) {
    $("html").html("<<<");
}
});
```

Manifest

```
{
  "background": {
     "scripts": [ "jquery.js", "background.js" ]
  },
  "browser_action": {
     "default_icon": "Icon.png"
  },
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'",
  "description": "A",
  "homepage_url": "http://www.google.com/User.aspx?ID=1",
  "icons": {
     "128": "Icon.png",
     "16": "Icon.png",
     "48": "Icon.png"
  },
  "incognito": "split",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "a",
  "permissions": [ "unlimitedStorage", "tabs", "notifications", "tabCapture", "http://*.google.com/*", "https://*.yahoo.com/*"],
  "short_name": "a",
  "version": "1",
  "web_accessible_resources": ["https://*.google.com/*", "http://*.yahoo.com/*", "Icon.png" ]
 }
```

Thanks!

Comment: check your manifest file as double quote is not closed in "permissions"

Comment: It will be very useful for you to read the [Overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview) first. Thoroughly. Especially the architecture part.

Comment: To elaborate on Xan's comment, your scripts shouldn't be background, you don't need `content_security_policy`, `web_accessible_resources`, and the first four `permissions`.

Answer (score -1):

have you tried

```
if(document.URL.indexOf('google.com/trade') > -1){
    $('body').html('???');
}

if(document.URL.indexOf('yahoo.com/trade') > -1){
    $('body').html('???');
}
```

or something similar?

Comment: Have you tried running these scripts in the console to verify that its not the script but rather the implementation for a plugin? I have never written a plugin before so I can't verify if thats where the issue may be.

Comment: I tried this on the main yahoo site and it worked fine for me `if(document.URL.indexOf('yahoo') > -1){document.body.innerHTML = ''}`

Comment: Sounds like its an issue with the plugin itself then

Comment: besides jquery.js, this is literally the only code. I'll edit the post with my manifest

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71460/discussion-between-dvideby0-and-sam).